# Express Regex all routes except api/login/

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I'm doing some authentication tasks in Express:

```
router.post(
    '*',
    expressJwt({
        secret: config.SECRET,
        getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring(req) {
            if (req.cookies.sessionUniversalCookie) {
                return req.cookies.sessionUniversalCookie;
            }

            return null;
        },
    })
);
```

I want to allow `/api/login`, so I want this route to ignore this path. This was my try, but this one does not work for post api calls.

```
router.post('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.baseUrl === '/api/login') {
        return next();
    }
    expressJwt({
        secret: config.SECRET,
        getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring(req) {
            if (req.cookies.sessionUniversalCookie) {
                return req.cookies.sessionUniversalCookie;
            }

            return null;
        },
    });
});
```

A good option would be to match all routes except `api/login` in the Regex. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to your second code, you want to pass the routing to the next section, if the routing path is '/api/login'.
Except '/api/login', another routing will handle the jwt authentication.

```
router.post('/api/login', (req, res, next) => {
    return next();
});

router.post('*', (req, res, next) => {
    expressJwt({
        secret: config.SECRET,
        getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring(req) {
            if (req.cookies.sessionUniversalCookie) {
                return req.cookies.sessionUniversalCookie;
            }

            return null;
        },
    });
});
```

So the above code will pass the routing to the next section if the route is '/api/login'.

In other cases, the route will go directly to the jwt section.

Comment: Hm, this call to `next()` is sending us to the next middleware, right?

Comment: Yes, In this case, the `router.post('*')` section.

Comment: But what if I want to exclude `/api/login` from `router.post('*')`?

Comment: You do not want to go to the `router.post('*')` from the `router.post('/api/login')`, right?

Comment: This route is checking the session cookies. I want to forbid all POST requests, except the one used for the login.

Comment: You might consider putting the `session cookies check` in the `/api/login` route, I am not sure.